# AWS-Cognito: Is it possible to edit the User Pool name after creating the User Pool?

Tags: typescript, amazon-cognito

I m trying to update User Pool name and User attributes in AWS-Cognito through my code. 
I could find the information on updating user attributes, but could not find anything on updating pool name. Any information on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the User Pool name in Amazon Cognito with the existing APIs. [UpdateUserPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserPool.html) allows a bunch of configurational changes, but it does not allow developers to modify the Pool Name.

Comment: Thanks, I guess they need to add it in their API. My code had a functionality to edit this, but in vain

Comment: @sum91 You could contact AWS Support, and they could make a feature request to the development team regarding this.

Comment: Aug 2022; still not there:  failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Updates are not allowed for property - UserPoolName.